# Unable to get value from JSON array of dictionaries in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

json response:
"result": {

```
   "user_images": [
        {
            "id": 113,
            "user_id": "160",
            "image": "1617349564.jpg",
            "image_title": "33"
          
        },
        {
            "id": 112,
            "user_id": "160",
            "image": "1617349541.jpg",
            "image_title": "22"
           
        },
        {
            "id": 111,
            "user_id": "160",
            "image": "1617349528.jpg",
            "image_title": "11"
        },
        ........
```

**code**: with this code i am getting response like above means all `user_images` array coming... **but here i need  `image_title` how to get that**.. if i run for loop getting error.. pls do help

```
  if let code = ((response.dict?["result"] as? [String : Any])){
      let userImages = code["user_images"] as? [String : Any]

   }
```

how to get `image_title` value from above array of dictionaries

Comment: I will suggest go for `Codables`. If you want to get it from here, you can use `userImages[0].image_title` to get the first one and you can use a loop to get all of them and put `userImages` in `if let userImages = code["user_images] as? [String: [String:Any]]`.

Comment: JSON is a pretty simple text format. There are only two (2) collection types, array `[]` and dictionary `{}`. The value for `user_images` is clearly an array but you treat it as dictionary.

Comment: @Rob, yes i want all `image_title` how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sol 1

```
if let code = response.dict?["result"] as? [String : Any]  {
  if let userImages = code["user_images"] as? [[String : Any]] {
      for item in userImages {
         print(item["image_title"])
      } 
   } 
}
```

Sol 2

```
if let code = response.dict?["result"] as? [String : Any]  { 
   do { 
       let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: code) 
       let decoder = JSONDecoder() 
       decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase 
       let res = try decoder.decode(Result.self, from: data) 
       let titles = res.userImages.map { $0.imageTitle } 
       print(titles) 
   }
   catch {
       print(error)
   } 
}
```

---

```
// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let userImages: [UserImage]
 
} 
// MARK: - UserImage
struct UserImage: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let userId, image, imageTitle: String
}
```

Comment: Just to add to @Sh-Khan's answer. The reason for the `[[String:Any]]` is because you're attempting to set `code` as a `Dictionary of String : Any` whereas the JSON is an `Array of Dictionary String : Any`. It's easy to look at it and think that you're using just an array, but that's not the case.

Comment: yes if i run for loop also got this error  `For-in loop requires '[String : Any]?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?`

Comment: You should probably safely unwrap the result of code. Notice the `?` in `as?` that means you're assuming it's an optional value. If you use something like `guard let safeCode = code else { return }` You'll be able to continue safely. Coding tip, try your best to always safely unwrap any `?` and NEVER use `!`

Answer (score 1):

#### Code from @Sh_Khan

```
if let code = response.dict?["result"] as? [String : Any]  {
  //You're using "as?" which means you're casting as an optional type. 
  //One simple solution to this is here where it's unwrapped using "if let"
  if let userImages = code["user_images"] as? [[String : Any]] {
      // [String:Any] is a Dictionary
      // [[String:Any]] is an Array of Dictionary
      for item in userImages {
         print(item["image_title"])
      } 
   } else {
      // We didn't unwrap this safely at all, do something else. 
}
```

Let's dive into this a little bit. This structure is a JSON Object

```
    {
        "id": 113,
        "user_id": "160",
        "image": "1617349564.jpg",
        "image_title": "33"
    }
```

But it's only a JSON object when it stands alone. Adding a key, or in this example `user_images` makes it a dictionary. Notice that the `[` is not wrapped around it. Meaning it's a standalone dictionary. If this was your object, and this alone, your original code would work, but you're dealing with an `Array` of `Dictionaries`.

```
"user_images":
    {
        "id": 113,
        "user_id": "160",
        "image": "1617349564.jpg",
        "image_title": "33"
    }
```

This line of code essentially means that you're expecting to get back that `Array` of `Dictionary`. Bear in mind, each value for the dictionary is not an array value, which is why you don't see something like this `[[[String: Any]]]` because the data isn't nested like that.

```
if let userImages = code["user_images"] as? [[String : Any]]
```

#### What's this about optionals?

An optional is basically a `nil` possible value that can be returned. Typically when working with JSON you cannot guarantee that you'll always receive a value for a given key. It's even possible for a key value pair to be completely missing. If that were to happen you'd end up with a crash, because it's not handled. Here are the most common ways to handle `Optionals`

```
var someString: String? //This is the optional one
var someOtherString = "Hello, World!" //Non-optional

if let unwrappedString1 = someString {
   //This code will never be reached
} else {
   //This code will, because it can't be unwrapped.
}

guard let unwrappedString2 = someString else {
   //This code block will run
   return //Could also be continue, break, or return someValue
} 

//The code will never make it here.
print(someOtherString)
```

Furthermore, you can work with optionals by chain unwrapping them which is a nifty feature.

```
var someString: String?
var someInt: Int?
var someBool: Bool?

someString = "Hello, World!"

//someString is not nil, but an important distinction to make, if any
//fail, ALL fail.
if let safeString = someString,
   let safeInt = someInt,
   let safeBool = someBool {
      //If the values are unwrapped safely, they will be accessible here.
      //In this case, they are nil, so this block will never be hit.
      //I make this point because of scope, the guard statement saves you from the 
      //scoping issue present in if let unwrapping.
      print(safeString)
      print(safeInt)
      print(safeBool)
}

guard let safeString = someString,
      let safeInt = someInt, 
      let safeBool = someBool {
         //This will be hit if a value is null
      return
}

//However notice the scope is available outside of the guard statement, 
//meaning you can safely use the values now without them being contained
//to an if statement. Despite this example, they would never be hit.
print(safeString)
print(safeInt)
print(safeBool)
```